# Multiple Processes of "Java Web Start Launcher" showing up in the Task Manager when uninstalling Java

Tags: windows-8.1, java, uninstall, task-manager, revo-uninstaller

A few days ago, I planned to uninstall Java because I don't need it anymore. I use an uninstaller named 'Revo Uninstaller' to do a thorough uninstallation of older versions of Java.

I was able to uninstall Java 7 Update 67 using Revo Uninstaller. Revo Uninstaller wasn't able to uninstall Java 8 Update 30-something and I don't know why. It was showing some error about "Windows Installer" so I just used the Control Panel's uninstallation tool. The Control Panel was able to uninstall it but after that, a number of processes named "Java Web Start Launcher" suddenly appeared on the Task Manager. There were many! I decided to shut down the computer because I needed to sleep.

The next day, I woke up and tried to uninstall another old version named "Java 8 Update 40" by using Revo Uninstaller. The uninstallation took a while then I noticed that my PC started running slow. So I went to the Task Manager and I saw that "Java Web Start Launcher" appearing again and again. It kept on creating a lot of them. Every time I scroll down, I see more and more processes of it. So I went to a task manager alternative named "Process Explorer" and tried to kill the Process Tree. It didn't work. It just kept on creating more. They took a lot of my CPU usage. My computer went slow so I held down the power button of my laptop to shut down my PC.

I'd like to know why this is happening. I don't want to uninstall Java 8 Update 40 and the last one named Java 8 Update 45 in the fear of this might happen again.

Could this be fixed? Is there a way to uninstall these Java versions without having another problem like this? Could I uninstall them manually? Like deleting some files in the Program Files folder in the C: drive or maybe removing some registry entries?

Thanks, I hope for an immediate answer.

I'm running Windows 8.1.

Comment: Although discontinued because the Java uninstaller now handles the removal of Java the proper way, JavaRA, will remove all traces of Java from your computer.  Although I suspect the problem is Revo Uninstaller not the Java uninstaller at this point.

Comment: Not sure, really. This also happened when I uninstalled one when I used the Control Panel's uninstaller. What is JavaRA?

Comment: So I searched google about JavaRa and saw that it's some Java tool by SingularLabs. It says it does a clean uninstallation of Java so I used it. I uninstalled the last two versions listed using it... Those "Java Web Start Launchers" didn't appear anymore. How do I know if all traces of Java were uninstalled? And thanks for telling me about JavaRa. :)

Comment: It generates a log.  As for how you know.  You just have to trust it claims to do it and it actually does it, and the fact it was discontinued becaue the Java uninstaller now does it, means the uninstaller will do it.  As for why it didn't work thats why I suggested it, easier just to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I experienced it similarly. I changed (not upgraded yet?) Windows7 to Windows10 and installed many Java related packages (like eclipse, Java SE runtime 32/64 etc.) Suddenly, the blue circle next to the cursor kept on spinning while I was not doing anything. So many *Java(TM) Web Start Launcher* processes running according to Task Manager. Even though they took 0~1% CPU time each, and they caused CPU and memory usage to reach 100%.

If this is your case, the following may help you, as it did me;
(Please bear with me that the following steps are based on Windows 10.)

1. Windows Key + R
2. Type *msconfig* and run it.
3. Go to the Service tab
4. Check *Hide all Microsoft Services*
5. Click *Disable all*
6. Go to the Startup tab
7. Disable all items
8. Optionally, in an administrative command prompt, run the following;

*Dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth*

9. Reboot

After this work, my computer has been running fine for last two days. Then I went back to the *msconfig* and I turned on the services I really need such as OneDrive and Dropbox stuff. (a debtor)<><

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem about three weeks ago and tried multiple solutions I found on the web. The solution that worked was:

1. Delete my Java folder (right-click on the folder and select Delete).    Then, all four versions of Java and the folder were (and still are) gone.
2. Run RKill and then MalwareBytes... no problems detected.
3. Run CCleaner and it removed some Java registry entries.
4. Shut down my laptop and then restart it.
5. Run CCleaner again (out of curiosity) and it deleted more Java registry entries.
6. Ran AVG scan... no problems detected.

Result: My laptop immediately ran normal speed and still does.

Thoughts:  I suspect the problem was caused by an unsuccessful installation of Java.  I had three versions of Java listed on my install/uninstall program listing and four in my Java folder.  The latest version was in the folder but not in the program listing.  I have not reinstalled Java yet, but my local computer repair technician thinks that should be alright to do.

More details on the original problem: Hundreds of copies of Web Start Launcher would launch after I would get on the web (per Task Manager), and that brought my laptop to a crawl.  When I tried to uninstall Java, Java attempted to install and locked up the laptop with hundreds of copies of Java Web Start Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Java Uninstaller is the recommended way to remove the problematic version.

As far as killing the multiple processes created by said defunct version of Java, while you may encounter windows error messages, if you continue to attempt to kill the process several times, it may eventually shut down the out of control processes.

The other thing you can do is to disable the "Java SE Auto Updater" item, located under the Startup Tab in System Configuration. If you see it there and it is checked, then uncheck it and before you close the 'System Configuration' window, click on the "Services" tab and scroll through the list to look for any "Java" items. If you find any, uncheck them too & click the "Apply" button, which will apply both actions. Click OK, and close the System Configuration window, after which you will be prompted to restart your computer. You should save any work you have open and then click OK to restart your computer.

If you're having trouble performing the above tasks for any reason, including that your computer is running slow because of the out of control process, reboot your computer into Safe Mode and then try the above steps to disable the rogue Java Startup entry.

If you absolutely need Java for some reason, the best thing to do after uninstalling the bad version, is to install the previously working version that did not cause this error and to set its security levels to maximum. But do not let it start with windows nor have it set to automatically update. The best advice here is to use it only as "On-Demand." Also, if you're browsers flag any Java plug-ins as "unsafe"-------you should listen to that warning and do not enable that unsafe plug-in.

If on the other hand, you're absolutely sure that you do not need Java and would like it and it's remnants gone from your system, you should definitely use the Java uninstaller.

As for further cleaning methods (i.e. scanning the registry to remove whats left of Java), this can be done-------but you must be careful!

Unless you actually know what you are doing, editing the registry without proper knowledge could be disastrous and could cause all types of system stability issues, including an un-bootable computer. This includes using the "Registry" cleaning function of CCleaner!

As a general rule of thumb, especially if you're just an average user with little to no knowledge of Windows Internals, it is **highly recommended** that you leave such editing to trained professionals only!

If you knew how to build an automobile engine, you probably wouldn't need to take your car to a mechanic, should you encounter any issues with it, but for those of us whom don't know the first thing about auto-mechanics, we usually concede to the fact that we're going to have to take the car into the shop for it's needed repairs, whether we like it or not. Well, the same thing can be said for computers.

Eating humble pie once in a while is a good thing for the soul and it might actually save you from future heartache as well. Take the advice of professionals and don't try this at home unless you are one!

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue, saying that I am unsure of the causation of the actual problem.. I came here to try and identify what went on, but have had no such luck.

Anyways, I fixed the machine via the following:

1) Boot in to safe mode: This prevents the wild and wacky processes from launching and prevents system slow down.

2) Recommendation: It may be worth carrying out a health check on the machine. So running a scan of MalwareBytes (google it) and HitmanPro (google it) to identify any malware and rootkits is recommended.

2) Uninstall all versions of Java in control panel where visible

3) Download CCleaner

4) Uninstall all versions of Java in CCLeaner where visible

5) Delete the Java folder in program files

6) Using CCleaner click the registry tab and "Scan for Issues". When I did this, I found numerous corruptions and unused extensions (naturally as we have just removed java from the machine).

Oh Of course, feel free to reinstall Java after the end of this process :).

Answer (score -1):

I gathered from the previous two answers that the gist of the remedy was to remove Java and its registry entries. Using the Control Panel I was unable to uninstall Java so followed the instructions to remove the Java directory and run CCLeaner. That seems to have solved the problem. I did notice however, that when re-installing Java it told me it would remove an older version of Java. I suspect that the older version is the cause. Running fine now - Thanks.